# Getting the distance between two locations using Google Maps Api (JSON)

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the distance between two locations using the Google API however this is the first time I hear about JSON and actually see its format. The variable $json_a should decode the JSON but when I try to get the distance I get "Notice: Undefined index: legs in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 24". I added a link so you can see how the JSON structure looks like. I'll also want these locations ordered by distance and if you can provide any tips about how I could do that it would be great. Thanks! :)

PS: I know MySQL is depreciated, I'll look into MySQLi or PDO ASAP.

```
//$origin = $_COOKIE['origin'];
//$id=$_GET['id'];

$origin = "Bucuresti+Avrig+30";
$id = 3;
$query = ("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE category_id='$id'");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$address = $row['Judet'] . '+' . $row['Localitate'] . '+' . $row['Strada'] . '+' . $row['Numar'];
$address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);

$fullurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $origin . '&destination=' . $address .  '&alternatives=true&sensor=true';
$json_a = json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true); 

echo $row['name'];
echo "<span class='badge'>" . $json_a['legs']['routes']['distance']['text'] . "</span></button>";
}
```

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Comanesti+Dimitrie+Ghica+13&destination=Brasov+1+Mai&alternatives=true&sensor=true

print_r shows me this:

```
Array ( [routes] => Array ( ) [status] => NOT_FOUND ) Array ( [routes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [bounds] => Array ( [northeast] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.1311305 ) [southwest] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4451446 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) ) [copyrights] => Map data ©2015 Google [legs] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 1.2 km [value] => 1168 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 2 mins [value] => 137 ) [end_address] => Șoseaua Colentina 2, București, Romania [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.1267169 ) [start_address] => Strada Avrig 30, București, Romania [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4451446 [lng] => 26.1311305 ) [steps] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.4 km [value] => 397 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 42 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4479077 [lng] => 26.1279682 ) [html_instructions] => Head northwest on Strada Avrig toward Aleea Avrig [polyline] => Array ( [points] => cugnGqvn~Ce@h@w@`AEDiArA_BnBm@r@QRsA~AeAlAaAjA ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4451446 [lng] => 26.1311305 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [1] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.2 km [value] => 158 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 22 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.447097 [lng] => 26.1263385 ) [html_instructions] => Turn left onto Strada Chiristigiilor [maneuver] => turn-left [polyline] => Array ( [points] => mfhnGybn~CJTj@rAZv@Rh@f@nAPh@ ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4479077 [lng] => 26.1279682 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [2] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.3 km [value] => 282 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 32 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4494197 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) [html_instructions] => Turn right onto Șoseaua Mihai Bravu [maneuver] => turn-right [polyline] => Array ( [points] => kahnGsxm~CiA@mAX[FGBMDWHEBc@Pa@T]TUPEBgBfB ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.447097 [lng] => 26.1263385 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [3] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.3 km [value] => 331 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 41 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.1267169 ) [html_instructions] => Turn right onto Șoseaua Colentina/DN2/E60/E85
Destination will be on the right
[maneuver] => turn-right [polyline] => Array ( [points] => {ohnG{pm~CYE[IoBk@oFeDYWYQq@[e@[ ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4494197 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) ) [via_waypoint] => Array ( ) ) ) [overview_polyline] => Array ( [points] => cugnGqvn~CaL|MgCxCv@hBn@`Bx@xBiA@mAXc@JoAd@{A`AgBfBYEkCu@iG}DkAm@e@[ ) [summary] => Strada Avrig and Șoseaua Colentina/DN2/E60/E85 [warnings] => Array ( ) [waypoint_order] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [bounds] => Array ( [northeast] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.131243 ) [southwest] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4438465 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) ) [copyrights] => Map data ©2015 Google [legs] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 1.3 km [value] => 1282 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 3 mins [value] => 153 ) [end_address] => Șoseaua Colentina 2, București, Romania [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.1267169 ) [start_address] => Strada Avrig 30, București, Romania [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4451446 [lng] => 26.1311305 ) [steps] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 9 m [value] => 9 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 1 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4450833 [lng] => 26.1312017 ) [html_instructions] => Head southeast on Strada Avrig [polyline] => Array ( [points] => cugnGqvn~CJM ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4451446 [lng] => 26.1311305 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [1] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.2 km [value] => 209 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 45 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4439255 [lng] => 26.1293794 ) [html_instructions] => Take the 1st right toward Șoseaua Mihai Bravu [polyline] => Array ( [points] => wtgnG_wn~CHCFAFAFAD@F@D@D@DBFH~@jCHRRj@BHZ`AJVPn@ ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4450833 [lng] => 26.1312017 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [2] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.7 km [value] => 733 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 66 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4494197 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) [html_instructions] => Turn right onto Șoseaua Mihai Bravu [maneuver] => turn-right [polyline] => Array ( [points] => qmgnGskn~CNf@KPGL_@n@]j@m@|@e@h@[Za@b@eBrAqBxAIFk@Z_@R{@X{@RiA@mAX[FGBMDWHEBc@Pa@T]TUPEBgBfB ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4439255 [lng] => 26.1293794 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) [3] => Array ( [distance] => Array ( [text] => 0.3 km [value] => 331 ) [duration] => Array ( [text] => 1 min [value] => 41 ) [end_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4521487 [lng] => 26.1267169 ) [html_instructions] => Turn right onto Șoseaua Colentina/DN2/E60/E85
Destination will be on the right
[maneuver] => turn-right [polyline] => Array ( [points] => {ohnG{pm~CYE[IoBk@oFeDYWYQq@[e@[ ) [start_location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4494197 [lng] => 26.1251047 ) [travel_mode] => DRIVING ) ) [via_waypoint] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [location] => Array ( [lat] => 44.4445541 [lng] => 26.130791 ) [step_index] => 1 [step_interpolation] => 0.36662061075431 ) ) ) ) [overview_polyline] => Array ( [points] => cugnGqvn~CTQNCZBJDFH~@jC\~@^jA\fANf@KPg@|@kAhBaAdAa@b@eBrA{B`BkAn@wBl@iA@mAXc@Je@Ni@T_Aj@[TgBfBYEkCu@iG}DkAm@e@[ ) [summary] => Șoseaua Mihai Bravu and Șoseaua Colentina/DN2/E60/E85 [warnings] => Array ( ) [waypoint_order] => Array ( ) ) ) [status] => OK )
```

Comment: print_r($json_a), and show us what array is coming

Comment: @Khushboo edited initial post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the first value of routes, you can use below code :-

```
$json_a['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text']
```

If you want to show all values then use `foreach`.

For sorting on values

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Now i get the kms for the second location but where it should show the kms for the first one it says Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\app2\test.php on line 24

Comment: your first array is empty. Array ( [routes] => Array ( ) [status] => NOT_FOUND )

Comment: I looked in the database and the fields there have data in them, they are not empty

Comment: but in array it is coming empty

Comment: Hmm... weird... any idea why?

Comment: That was indeed true! Thanks! Any idea how I can sort them so that the lowest distance entry gets shown first and so on?

Comment: you can use asort() function for sorting on keywords

Comment: I checked the function on PHP.net but it's foggy for me. :D Can you please provide an example?

Comment: added example in my answer for sort

Comment: I got that to work using $row instead of your array but I don't know if this method will work in my case because I only have an address and a name in the database, the distance gets calculated by Google Api and that's where the sorting has to be done somehow.

Comment: so after this part: $fullurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $origin . '&destination=' . $address .  '&alternatives=true&sensor=true';
$json_a = json_decode((file_get_contents($fullurl)),true);

Comment: yes, because after this also, you are getting an array and which can be sort

Comment: I'm probably not changing what I should change but i'm getting this 0: 3 1: 2 2: 5 3: 6 4: 1

Comment: 0: 3 1: 2 2: 5 3: 6 4: 1  ??? Please make new question on this, will reply on that, as this is a new topic :)

Comment: Ok, will post it in a second then :)

Comment: I can't post a new question yet, have to wait 90 minutes between questions, will ask in 30 minutes and let you know here, ok?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250935/sorting-an-array-from-db-based-on-google-api-distance

Comment: checking that only :)]